# Show Element Using Ng-Show on Ng-Click - Angular

Tags: angularjs

Using the code below I am trying to show the UL element ng-click but it does not work. There are no any errors and I don't understand why it does't work like that.

Could you please take a look and explain what is made wrong?

Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="nsCtrl as ctrl">
    <div class="question">
        Click <span ng-click="ctrl.showTable();">here</span>.
    </div>
    <ul ng-show="self.visible = false">
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Angular

```
<script>
    angular.module('snApp', [])
        .controller('nsCtrl', [function(){
            var self = this;

            self.showTable = function(){
                self.visible = true
            }

        }])
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is here:

```
ng-show="self.visible = false"
```

Should be:

```
ng-show="ctrl.visible === false"
```

or, better:

```
ng-show="!ctrl.visible"
```

or even:

```
ng-hide="ctrl.visible"
```

As a side note: are you sure you want to show list if `visible` property is false? Is it possible you did invert the test or the assignment in the controller?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not work again"? Are you sure `self.showTable()` is executed (`console.log()` is your friend... :-) ?

Comment: the function is executing, I checked this. but the UL element does not show on click in all the methods you suggested

Comment: did you try `ng-show="self.visible"`, i.e. inverting the test? :-)

Comment: yes it doesn't help as well. but thanks for help anyway. I solved the issue

Comment: Please add the solution or remove the question.

Comment: actually it has solved with your help :) so please post a solution, just mention that ctrl should added to HTML instead of the 'self' variable.

Comment: <ul ng-show="ctrl.visible"> to HTML and self.visible = !self.visible; to the controller

Comment: Changed answer... :-) If you use `self.visible = !self.visible` in the controller, you should also change the name of the function from `showTable` to `toggleTable` ...

Comment: Yes, I noticed it, but as I need to  have it only once, I changed it to the self.visible = true; Thanks for you kind help!